# Does g++ inline the following function?

Tags: c++, inline

Let's say I have two functions:

```
void foo() {
    // A big function
}

// This is a wrapper to foo
inline void bar() {
    // couple of lines -- simple ones. I promise!
    foo();
}
```

I'm aware that compiler is the one that eventually decides whether or not to inline a function. What i'm wondering is when it comes to wrappers (that call other functions), how deep does the compiler do the analysis?

Does it stop inside `bar()` and just copies whatever is inside wherever `bar()` is called or does it also look into `foo()`? How is this different if `foo()` is inside a pre-compiled library that is dynamically linked to `bar()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to know for sure is to check the disassembly.

In general I never worry about such micro-optimizations because I trust the compiler to make the right choice in inlining decisions. Only if profiling shows me that function calls are causing significant overhead would I attempt to change the compiler's choice.

Comment: I agree - some programmers get bogged down in the fine detail and miss the bigger picture - where the real savings can be made.

Answer (score 1):

If everything is in the same translation unit and optimization is enabled, it's might be inlined, but it most likely depends on the compiler's code analysis and optimization settings. You can't expect it to do it (or avoid it).

If `foo()` is in its own translation unit (or even its own library) it won't be inlined (as that's not possible). Things like "link time code optimization" (e.g. available in MSVC) might try to inline code over different translation units, but it won't be able to inline code sitting in a dynamic library.